# Can't Type in input box after minimizing browser

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Vistual Studio 2012 with Bootstrap 3 (cosmo-bootstrap themes) to style my page. The page works fine when the browser is maximized; however, I can't type in my input text box if the page is restored down to certain size. Has anyone else has this issue? What can I do to solve this issue? 
Below is one of my layout page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="../../Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../Content/cosmo-boostrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
@* <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>*@

<div id="status">
</div>

</div>
    <div id="page">
        <header class="container">
            <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> 
                    </button>
                   <div id="logo" id="logo" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-5 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                            <img src="../../Images/logo.png" alt="THE BOOK UP" class="image-responsive" /> @Html.ActionLink(SessionWrapper.Student.FirstName +" "+ SessionWrapper.Student.LastName ,"UserProfile","Student", null, new {id = SessionWrapper.Student.UserId})
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="ListBook" class= "nav">
                       @* @Html.ActionLink("List Books", "ListBook", "Student")*@
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ListBook", "Student")'">List Books</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="FindBook" class="nav">
                       @* @Html.ActionLink("Find Books", "FindBook", "Student")*@
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("FindBook", "Student")'">Find Books</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id= "index" class="nav">
                       @* @Html.ActionLink("Add Books", "AddBook", "Student")*@
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddBook", "Student")'">Add Book</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="addUser" class="nav">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddUser","Home")'">Add User</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Logoff" class="nav">
                       @* @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account", new { onclick="logOut()" })*@
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" onclick="logOut(1)">Log out</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="body" class="container">
            <section id="main" class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
            <section id="sidebar" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <table style="background-color: black;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                            <div id="AddCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-wrap="true">
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/Desert.jpg" id="pic1" alt="Desert" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Desert</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/koala.png" id="pic2" alt="Koala" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Koala</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/Jellyfish.jpg"  id="pic3" alt="Jelly Fish" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Jelly Fish</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/Tulips.jpg"  id="pic4" alt="Tulips" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Tulips</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                             <div id="AddCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-wrap="true">
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/Desert.jpg" id="pic1" alt="Desert" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Desert</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/koala.png" id="pic2" alt="Koala" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Koala</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/Jellyfish.jpg"  id="pic3" alt="Jelly Fish" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Jelly Fish</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="../../Images/adds/Tulips.jpg"  id="pic4" alt="Tulips" class="thumbnail image-responsive">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h3>Tulips</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
        </section>
        <hr />
        <footer class="container">
            <p>&copy; of K&M Systems Solution <a href="www.k&m.com">K&M</a>. </p>
        </footer>
    </div>

     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   @* <script data-main="scripts/js/mbtest" src="~/Scripts/js/require.js"></script>*@
    <script src="../../Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

   <script>
       $('#pic1').attr("src", '../../Images/adds/koala.png');
       //$('.carousel').carousel({
       //    interval: 3000
       //});
       @*  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
             FB.init({
                 appId: '296813847191603',
                 xfbml: true,
                 version: 'v2.1'
             });

             FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                 statusChangeCallback(response);
             });

         };

         (function (d, s, id) {
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));*@



         function logOut(e) {
            @* window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                 alert('init');
                 FB.init({
                     appId: '296813847191603',
                     xfbml: true,
                     version: 'v2.1'
                 });
             };

             if (typeof FB.logout == 'function') {
                 if (FB.getAuthResponse()) {
                     FB.logout(function (response) { location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")'; });
                     return;
                 }
             } else {
                 location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';
                 return;
             }*@

             if (e == 1) {
                 location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';
             }
         }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was my Sidebar was taking over the main form. In my css file, I added the lines shown below; the issue was fixed.

```
#sidebar
{
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

Comment: I got lucky finding this you saved me, because this was really bugging me.  I simply made a class called .overlap{ overflow: hidden;}  added to the outside column and it fixed my issue.